# Proof of $ g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}=-c^2$ in GR

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

The differential proper time $d\tau$ is defined by

$$
    c^2 d\tau^2 = -g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu \otimes dx^\nu
$$

So i believe we can think of $d\tau^2$ as 
$$
    d\tau^2 = -\frac{1}{c^2}ds^2
$$
where $ds^2$ is the inner product.

I've read that 
\begin{equation}
    g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}=-c^2
\end{equation}
How can I (rigorously) derive this last equation from the first? Is there a way? Physics texts say it is, but I have not seen it done (apart from obviously not acceptable "proofs" that simply "divide" the first equation by $d\tau^2$ on both sides).

Comment: OK. Start by telling us what kind of object you think that $d\tau$ actually *is*? If you think it's some kind of function, what are the domain and codomain? Your answer to this will profoundly affect the answers we might write, all of which are going to say "chain rule" somewhere in the middle, but in various different forms.

Comment: @JohnHughes I don't really know about $d\tau$. I would say that $d\tau^2$ is a symmetric (0,2)-tensor, of the type $TM\times TM\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
That said, I learned quite a bit about manifolds and differential forms some time ago, so I should be able to understand most arguments.

Comment: @JohnHughes $d\tau$ is usually written as the square root of $d\tau^2$, but that never really made sense for me: the square root of a (0,2)-tensor

Comment: Oh,I'm quite happy with a description of what $d\tau^2$ is; now I know where we stand. Assuming that you think that $x^\mu$ is a real-valued function on $M$, we're probably good to go. (Only I won't be the one writing and answer, because I have to run do something else). Very short answer: chain rule. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes yes, I do think that! (More concretely, $x^\mu = \pi^\mu \circ \phi$, where $\phi$ is a chart, if I understand correctly)

Comment: @JohnHughes Btw if one of thee days you have some time, I'd love to see an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Proper time for a timelike path $x^\mu(\lambda)$ is defined by
$$
\tau = \frac{1}{c} \int \left( - g_{\mu \nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda} \frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}\right)^{1/2} d\lambda
$$
where we integrate over a part of the path. So differentiating with respect to $\lambda$ and squaring we find 
$$
c^2 \left(\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda} \right)^2 = - g_{\mu \nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda} \frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}.
$$

Using the chain rule we find
$$
g_{\mu \nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda} \frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda} = g_{\mu \nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau} \frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau} \left(\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda} \right)^2,
$$
which gives the required equation.

In fact you have probably already seen a very similar thing in differential geometry for regular curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parameterized by their arc length. Given an interval $I$, a curve $\alpha: I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ the arc length is defined by
$$
s(t) = \int_{t_0}^t \lvert \alpha'(s) \rvert ds = \int_{t_0}^t \left( \alpha'(s) \cdot \alpha'(s) \right)^{1/2} ds.
$$
Then we have $\frac{ds}{dt} = \lvert \alpha'(s) \rvert$ which is equal to $1$ if $\alpha$ is parameterized by its arc length.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to derive the result from the definition of $d\tau^2$ (that I wrote) :)

Comment: Well you could write $\tau = \int \sqrt{d\tau^2(V(\lambda),V(\lambda))}d\lambda$ where $V$ is the velocity of the curve. But if you really want a straightforward argument from that first equation to your last, you're probably not going to find it. Even if your physics textbook might not mention it, what you're in fact doing is reparameterizing your curve so that it's parameterized by it's proper time. To do that you need to find the proper time in function of your old parameter $\lambda$.